# data sharding design for multi data source

Tags: database, database-connection, connection-pooling, arangodb, sharding

I use arangodb in my project and I want to save different data in different instances, like data sharding. But arangodb doesn't support connect to two db instances that are not belong to one cluster simultaneously.
so I have two designs as below:

```
    ----------------
    | data router  |
    ----------------
        |       |           key1: proc1
        |         |         key2: proc2
        |           |       key3: proc3
        |             |     
        |               |   //config data
        |                 | 
  -------------     -------------
  |data proc1 |     |data proc2 |                       
  -------------     -------------
  | db1(host1)|     | db2(host2)|
  -------------     -------------
```

In this mode, I have different `data proc` service with the same code and different configuration file, and each can only communicate to the fixed db instance. Data router receive the command and connect to different proc according to the config data.

I think this is simple to implement but not graceful. Because the several `proc`s are not equally receive the requests. And a little different to horizontal scaling.

Another choice is:

```
    -------------           key1: host1     
    | data proc |           key2: host2     
    -------------           key3: host3     
        |     |                     
        |       |           //config data
        |         | 
  ---------     ---------
  | host1 |     | host2 |
  ---------     ---------
```

In this way, I must implement a common `data proc` which can connect to all db instances, like a connecting pool in some way. `data proc` can route the request and connect to the right db(host).

I think this way is better because `data proc` is stateless and easy to scaling. but I think it more difficult than the above one. I don't know something like this to act as a connection pool across multiple db instances.

Is any suggestion for this?